# Auto Complete to Windows input queue from text on printed screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a bin which output hostnames to `stdout` in following format (Usually, it is ~20 lines):

```
ldn0000000002;ldn0000000040;ldn00000000055;ldn0000000117;nyk0000000001;nyk0000000002;tky0000000001
```

Then I would investigate several of them by `ssh <hostname>` (for instance, `ssh ldn0000000117`). Copy and paste using `Ctrl+[`, `arrow-keys`, `space`, `arrow-keys`, `space`, and then `Ctrl+]` would take me loads of time to highlight the text I want to copy.

Is it possible have something similar to autocomplete which I just have to type `l` and hit some key (e.g. `tab`) it would provide `ldn0000000` to the windows input queue (like `:history` aka `Ctrl+{`), and then hit `1` (now `ldn00000001`) and `tab` would complete `ldn0000000117`?

The output can be piped to any bin (e.g. `sed`) to reformat to newline delimited or any format if required.

Alternative solution which eliminate the need of `arrow-keys` is also welcomed!

*I don't have ownership of the host, so I cannot change any files on the remote host.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to auto-complete. So, alternative plan is to improve your cursor movement.

In copy/scrollback mode, you are able to use some movement keys. (from `screen(1)`)

```
Movement keys:
h, C-h, or left arrow move the cursor left.
j, C-n, or down arrow move the cursor down.
k, C-p, or up arrow move the cursor up.
l ('el') or right arrow move the cursor right.
0 (zero) or C-a move to the leftmost column.
+ and - positions one line up and down.
H, M and L move the cursor to the leftmost column of the top, center or bottom line of the window.
| moves to the specified absolute column.
g or home moves to the beginning of the buffer.
G or end moves to the specified absolute line (default: end of buffer).
% jumps to the specified percentage of the buffer.
^ or $ move to the leftmost column, to the first or last non-whitespace character on the line.
w, b, and e move the cursor word by word.
B, E move the cursor WORD by WORD (as in vi).
f/F, t/T move the cursor forward/backward to the next occurence of the target. (eg, '3fy' will move the cursor to the 3rd 'y' to the right.)
; and , Repeat the last f/F/t/T command in the same/opposite direction.
C-e and C-y scroll the display up/down by one line while preserving the cursor position.
C-u and C-d scroll the display up/down by the specified amount of lines while preserving the cursor position. (Default: half screen-full).
C-b and C-f scroll the display up/down a full screen.

Searching:
? Vi-like search backward.
C-a s Emacs style incremental search forward.
C-r Emacs style reverse i-search.
n Find next search pattern.
N Find previous search pattern.
```

In your case,

1. `Ctrl+[` - into copy/scrollback mode.
2. `?ldn` - backward search a word `ldn` from current cursor position.
3. `n` - move cursor to next candidates.
4. `space` (when the cursor position moves to your wishes) set the first mark.
5. `e` - move cursor to the end of a word.
6. `space` - set the second mark and end copy/scrollback mode.

The arrow-keys will not appear anywhere. :)